# cocos2d coutdown timer with frames

Tags: timer, cocos2d-iphone

I know that there are couple of questions here about a countdown timer but I couldn't find anything with frame sets and also to update a label like: mm:ss [minutes:seconds].

Anyone can give me an idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to keep track of the elapsed seconds using a scheduler. For that, schedule a function with one second as-

```
[self schedule:@selector(countTime:) interval:1];
```

increment totalSeconds in the timer and calculate time as below.

you will get

```
int minutes = totalSeconds/60;
int seconds = totalSeconds%60;

label.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",minutes, seconds];
```